# Grails save method gives error rejected value

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

While I am saving a `User` object it gives me the below error

My Save code

```java
User user = new User();
user.surname = "Test";
user.name = "Manoj";
user.save();
```

Validation error

```
grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation error whilst flushing entity 
[User]:
- Field error in object 'User' on field 'surname': rejected value [null]; codes [User.surname.nullable.error.User.surname,User.surname.nullable.error.surname,User.surname.nullable.error.java.lang.String,User.surname.nullable.error,stream.surname.nullable.error.User.surname,stream.surname.nullable.error.surname,stream.surname.nullable.error.java.lang.String,stream.surname.nullable.error,User.surname.nullable.User.surname,User.surname.nullable.surname,User.surname.nullable.java.lang.String,User.surname.nullable,stream.surname.nullable.User.surname,stream.surname.nullable.surname,stream.surname.nullable.java.lang.String,stream.surname.nullable,nullable.User.surname,nullable.surname,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [surname,class User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
```

User class:

```java
class User {
    String surname
    String name
}
```

I cannot set surname nullable true because its required field.

Comment: Is this really the error on that save?  Depending on your version of grails and settings like `failOnError` you might see an error from another save attempt.

Comment: failOnError also gives same error. my grails version is 2.5.0. updating same to question also.

Comment: The actual problem still is something else then. When is the error happening - right on the save via exception (due to failOnError) - e.g. what gives you the validation exception?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a class for a pre-existing database and this was not mapped properly, that might explain the error.

I say this because I don't see constraints or mapping.